# Is codicons available in webviews

Tags: vscode-extensions

I have few webviews and I am using the [font-awesome](http://fontawesome.com) fonts icons, but I would like to use the [codicons](https://microsoft.github.io/vscode-codicons/dist/codicon.html), is there a way to use codeicons in webview using [ThemeIcon](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#ThemeIcon) without manually downloading the svg from github and add it to the webview resources?

Comment: How about you download the css file along with the font and include these two in your project and reference them back.

Download codicon font and css : https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tree/e14cf0ff92f022d20f00bdd5b9e173af3f108a87/src/vs/base/browser/ui/codiconLabel/codicon.

Comment: @ShahriarHossain as I mentioned this is one possibility to download the SVG or CSS (_as you've mentioned_) but then I need to manually keep the downloaded assets in sync with the repo whenever updated, and also this isn't any different from packaging FontAwesome really. Since codeicons is already packaged with vscode thought it would be exposed to the webview.

Comment: i am also surprised to see it's not integrated with webview by default.

Answer (score 0):

There is a webview sample that uses codicons in vscode extensions sample repository:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/webview-codicons-sample

It still requires to include `.ttf` and `.css` files but they are published as npm module: [vscode-codicons](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vscode-codicons)

---

An open issue to support codicons in webview: [#95199](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/95199)